# Bad quantifier. Unity

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, unity3d

Не понимаю в чём проблема , [тут](https://regex101.com/r/n6Majh/1) нормально ищет.

А в Unity ругается:

```
 ArgumentException: parsing "[\/]+[Resources\/Icon\/]+[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,30}+[.]+[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,10}" - Bad quantifier.
Parameter name: [\/]+[Resources\/Icon\/]+[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,30}+[.]+[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,10}
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Syntax.Parser.ParseGroup (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Syntax.Group group, RegexOptions options, System.Text.RegularExpressions.Syntax.Assertion assertion)
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Syntax.Parser.ParseRegularExpression (System.String pattern, RegexOptions options)
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.CreateMachineFactory (System.String pattern, RegexOptions options)
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.InitNewRegex ()
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Init ()
```

Сама функция `trimLink()`:

```
   void trimLink() {
        string URLiconObj="D:/Unity/terranetools.git/Assets/Resources/Icon/C0092173000.png";
        string pattern = @"[\/]+[Resources\/Icon\/]+[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,30}+[.]+[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,10}";
        var result = Regex.Matches(URLiconObj, pattern).Cast<Match>().ToList();
        if(result.Count>=0) {
            URLiconObj = result[0].ToString();
        } else {
            URLiconObj = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Думаю, оно про `{5,30}+` ругается.  Вы сначала пишете «от 5 до 30», а потом «от одного до бесконечности».

Comment: @Ainar-G от 1 до 10 , а не до бесконечности . Можно написать как должно быть ? Я не совсем понял что править . Буду очень благодарен

Comment: @Ainar-G и я пишу . Как я понимаю это до "."{5,30} и после точки{1,10} должно искаться

Comment: regex101 не поддерживает синтаксис регулярных выражений .NET. Выражение для PCRE не обязательно будет работать в .NET.

Comment: Для поиска единственно возможного совпадения используется не `Regex.Matches`, а `Regex.Match`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная причина ошибки — несовместимость регулярных выражений PCRE и .NET.

`{5,30}+` не является двойным квантификатором, это один **"сверхжадный" кванитификатор** означает от 5 до 30 без возможности пересмотра найденной последовательности символов (при отсутствии совпадения последующих шаблонов) в квантифицируемой подмаске. **Проблема только в том, что этот "сверхжадный" квантификатор не поддерживается библиотекой регулярных выражений .NET.** Вам нужно использовать лишь `{5,30}`.

Кроме того, `[Resources\/Icon\/]+` — это символьный класс, который находит `R`, `e`, `s`, `o`, `u`, `r`, `c`, `s`, `/`, `I`, `n`, один и более раз. Необходимо убрать скобки и `+`, `Resources/Icon/`.

НЕ НАДО экранировать символы `/`, косая черта не является специальным метасимволом в регулярных выражениях. Он экранируется только в литералах, где используется в качестве разделителя. В .NET такая форма записи не поддерживается.

Для поиска единственно возможного совпадения используется не `Regex.Matches`, а `Regex.Match`.

Если вам очень нужно использовать подход с регулярными выражениями, используйте

```
void trimLink() {
    string URLiconObj="D:/Unity/terranetools.git/Assets/Resources/Icon/C0092173000.png";
    string pattern = @"/Resources/Icon/[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,30}\.[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,10}";
    var result = Regex.Match(URLiconObj, pattern);
    URLiconObj = result.Success ? result.Value : "";
}
```

См. [пример работы выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2FResources%2FIcon%2F%5B0-9a-zA-Z%5D%7B5%2C30%7D%5C.%5B0-9a-zA-Z%5D%7B1%2C10%7D&i=D%3A%2FUnity%2Fterranetools.git%2FAssets%2FResources%2FIcon%2FC0092173000.png) в **.NET-совместимом онлайн-сервисе**.

Если нужно получить подстроку, начиная от `/Resources/Icon/`, используйте

```
string URLiconObj="D:/Unity/terranetools.git/Assets/Resources/Icon/C0092173000.png";
Console.WriteLine(URLiconObj.Substring(URLiconObj.IndexOf("/Resources/Icon/")));
```

[Пример кода](https://ideone.com/JFRFRS)

Answer (score 0):

`{5,30}+` — ошибка.  Вы указываете сразу два квантификатора:
`{5,30}`, который говорит «от 5 до 30», и `+`,
который говорит «от 1 до +∞».  Вот верное регулярное выражение, без
лишнего `+`:

```
[\/]+[Resources\/Icon\/]+[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,30}[.]+[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,10}
```

Comment: `+` в `{5,30}+` не означает от 1 до бесконечности, этот "сверхжадный" кванитификатор означает от 5 до 30 без возможности пересмотра найденной последовательности символов (при отсутствии совпадения последующих шаблонов) в квантифицируемой подмаске. Проблема только в том, что этот "сверхжадный" квантификатор не поддерживается библиотекой регулярных выражений .NET. Кстати, тут не одна эта ошибка.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  В каком стандарте такая возможность?  Насколько я знаю, в _POSIX_ это _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew У меня сработало .А где ошибки ещё ?

Comment: PCRE, Java, Onigmo.... @IvanTriumphov "Сработало" не значит, что выражение написано верно. Если вам надо найти только то что от `/Resources/Icon/`, так и пишите, `/Resources/Icon/`. `[\/]+[Resources\/Icon\/]+` - пример того, как очень часто ошибаются пользователи, которые плохо знают регулярные выражения. `[a/d]` находит `a`, `/` или `d`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Можно написать правильное выражение тогда ? Я регулярками пользуюсь только в крайних случаях, когда не избежать этого. Когда то давно их изучал, но с тех пор много воды утекло

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Тогда зачем вы его здесь используете? [`URLiconObj.Substring(URLiconObj.IndexOf("/Resources/Icon/"))`](https://ideone.com/JFRFRS)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  https://regex101.com/r/n6Majh/2 тут я переделал как вы советовали и у меня находит кусок "s/Resources/Icon/C0092173000.png"

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew А всё догнал спасибо https://regex101.com/r/n6Majh/3

Comment: @IvanTriumphov НЕ используйте regex101 для тестирования регулярных выражений .NET. [Вот демо](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2fResources%2fIcon%2f%5b0-9a-zA-Z%5d%7b5%2c30%7d%5c.%5b0-9a-zA-Z%5d%7b1%2c10%7d&i=D%3a%2fUnity%2fterranetools.git%2fAssets%2fResources%2fIcon%2fC0092173000.png). НЕ НАДО экранировать символы `/`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100747/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-wiktor-stribizew).